# Como funcionen logicas en SFrame en Python?

Tags: python

Estoy nuevo con python pero conozco bien R. 
Quiero obtener ciertas casas con Python gracias a condiciones logicas que estan casas con mas de 2000 metros cuadrados pero menos de 4000 metros cuadrados. Utilizo [este sitio web](https://turi.com/products/create/docs/generated/graphlab.SFrame.html) para entender como utilizar las condiciones logicas pero no logro a un resultado.

Aqui esta mi solicitud :

```
housesRangeSqft = test_data[(test_data('sqft_living'>=2000)) & (test_data('sqft_living'<=4000))]
```

Pero me da el error siguiente en jupyter notebook :

> ```
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-40-7e39708087dd> in <module>()
> ----> 1 housesRangeSqft = test_data[(test_data('sqft_living'>=2000)) & (test_data('sqft_living'<=4000))]
> TypeError: 'SFrame' object is not callable
> ```

Aquí esta la estructura de `test_data`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que parece intentas hacer un filtro lógico, en python los paréntesis indican llamada a método o función, como un objeto `SFrame` no se puede ejcutar obtienes ese error. El problema es que para acceder a la columna haces algo como:

```
test_data('sqft_living'>=2000)
```

Cuando debería ser así:

```
test_data['sqft_living']>=2000
```

Observa como se usan corchetes, no paréntesis para obtener la columna (igual que si fuera un diccionario simple de Python).

El código debería ser así:

```
housesRangeSqft = test_data[(test_data['sqft_living']>=2000) & (test_data['sqft_living']<=4000)]
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias ! ¿Y como puedo saber el número de líneas de este casas y el de `test_data` para hacer un proporción ? Hizo `ratio = housesRangeSqft.num_rows()/test_data.num_rows()` pero me da 0 mientras que `housesRangeSqft.num_rows()`vale 1828 y `test_data.num_rows()` vale 4229

Comment: @Marine1 seguramente usas Python 2.7, en Python 2.x el operador `/` retorna por defecto el mismo tipo de dato que recibe (esto no pasa en Python 3.x). En este caso ambos son enteros por lo que retorna solo la parte entera. Puedes forzar la salida haciendo un casting a `float` de uno de los datos: `ratio = float(housesRangeSqft.num_rows())/test_data.num_rows()` Otra opción es usar el operador de Python 3 en Python 2 mediante `from __future__ import division`